# My SHA1 key changes after formatting my PC. I am unable to submit new version to play store

Tags: android, sha1

I am getting below error from Play Store while uploading new version to existing app.

> Upload failed You uploaded an APK that is signed with a different
>   certificate to your previous APKs. You must use the same certificate.
>   Your existing APKs are signed with the certificate(s) with
>   fingerprint(s): [ SHA1:
>   5D:BC:1C:3E:7A:9E:16:7C:C9:1A:95:2E:82:7F:62:2F:F8:C7:87:D7 ] and the
>   certificate(s) used to sign the APK you uploaded have fingerprint(s):
>   [ SHA1: 24:75:9A:E9:A0:D8:AA:C9:EA:71:79:16:CB:08:9D:8C:2E:41:45:05 ]

Since, I formatted my PC after my first version submit. So SHA1 key changed now.

Can you please help to fix this issue?

Thanks

Comment: Did you loose your old key file in the format?

Comment: You have to use your old keystore to upload the file..otherwise it will not upload on the p;lay store...Always keep in the mind..Keystore is also import like your application code...

Comment: are you able to resolve this issue? how do you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

When you format your PC, your debug keystore with new android studio is changed. To upload your APK file to play store, you need a release keystore that you used previously.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry to say - but if you loose the certificate you had before you lost possibility to update this particular application. All you can do is to change application package and to place it as new app. Please keep your keystore in safe place in future.